# Files.newOutputStream(path, CREATE_NEW, DELETE_ON_CLOSE) does not write to file

Tags: java, nio

I have the following code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

import static java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption.CREATE_NEW;
import static java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption.DELETE_ON_CLOSE;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try (OutputStream outputStream = Files.newOutputStream(Paths.get("test"), CREATE_NEW, DELETE_ON_CLOSE)) {
            outputStream.write(123);
            outputStream.flush();
            System.out.println("done");
        }
    }
}
```

I put a break point on the call to `System.out.println` and inspected my working directory. There was no file called `test`. Why isn't the output stream writing to a file?

Comment: Hmm... works for me (using a `Thread.sleep` instead of a breakpoint). What OS are you running on?

Comment: OSX. It works for me if I remove `DELETE_ON_CLOSE` as well.

Comment: I think what is happening is that Unix based operating systems immediately delete the file because deleted files with open file handles can still be accessed. This seems to violate the API though.

Comment: Yes, it does - I'll try on Linux and see if I can reproduce. (As an aside, it would be easier for people to reproduce this if you'd provide a *complete* app, including imports.)

Comment: I experience the same behaviour on Linux, @Max - `DELETE_ON_CLOSE` documentation does state "Many of the details as to when and how the file is deleted are implementation specific and therefore not specified."

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think there is any solution to this question. I do think that there should be a warning in the documentation `Files.newOutputStream` that states this may happen when using `DELETE_ON_CLOSE`.

Comment: On linux showing the same problem to me. The file is not created. But on windows it was getting created until the try block is completed. But not accessible.

Comment: Why do you care? If the file is to be deleted on close, why bother writing it at all?

Comment: @EJP I want to have a temporary file and not worry about deleting it.

Comment: @Max Have a look at my updated answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason is that on Linux you can delete a file from a directory even the file is open (appropriate permissions silently assumed here). Under Windows it's not possible.

From the source of [sun.nio.fs.UnixChannelFactory](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/2709b0da4d0f/src/solaris/classes/sun/nio/fs/UnixChannelFactory.java#l273)

> // unlink file immediately if delete on close. The spec is clear that
>   // an implementation cannot guarantee to unlink the correct file when
>   // replaced by an attacker after it is opened.
>   if (flags.deleteOnClose) {
>   ...

If you amend your code as

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    outputStream.write(123);
    outputStream.flush();
    System.out.println("flush...");
    Thread.sleep(10_000);
}
```

You are able to see that the file is open but already deleted

```
# assumed that the code write to Paths.get("/tmp/test")
lsof | grep "/tmp/test"
...  /tmp/test (deleted)
```

**edit** If you only want to ensure that a temporary file is removed when your application quits, have a look at the snippet below.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import static java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption.CREATE_NEW;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File file = new File("/tmp/test");
        file.deleteOnExit();
        System.out.println("tempFile = " + tempFile);
        try (OutputStream outputStream = Files.newOutputStream(file.toPath(),
                CREATE_NEW)) {
            outputStream.write(123);
            outputStream.flush();
            System.out.println("done");
        }
        System.out.printf("%s exists: %s%n", file, file.exists());
    }
}
```

The file `/tmp/test` will be removed at the moment the application finished.

output (the file still exists at this time)

```
/tmp/test exists: true
```

if you now check on the console

```
$ ls /tmp/test
ls: cannot access '/tmp/test': No such file or directory
```

In case you don't even care about the file name you might consider to use a randomly generated one.

```
File tempFile = File.createTempFile("foo_", ".tmp", new File("/tmp"));
```

**edit** Another solution could be.

1. create the file (prefer to use a random temporary file name)
2. open an `InputStream`
3. open the `OutputStream` with `DELETE_ON_CLOSE`

Doing it in that order it would work as you expect.

Find below a working snippet.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import static java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import static java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption.APPEND;
import static java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption.DELETE_ON_CLOSE;
import static java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption.READ;

public class DeleteOnClose {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Path path = Paths.get("/tmp/test");
        System.out.println("before create: " + Files.exists(path));
        Files.createFile(path);
        System.out.println("after create: " + Files.exists(path));
        try (InputStream in = Files.newInputStream(path, READ);
                OutputStream out = Files.newOutputStream(path, APPEND, 
                        DELETE_ON_CLOSE)) {
            out.write("Hello file!".getBytes(UTF_8));
            out.flush();

            for (int c = in.read(); c >= 0; c = in.read()) {
                System.out.print((char) c);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println("after close: " + Files.exists(path));
    }
}
```

output

```
before create: false
after create: true
Hello file!
after close: false
```

Comment: `deleteOnExit` does not work for me because this is a long-running process (a service). Using `deleteOnExit` could cause the disk to become full before the JVM exists.

Comment: @Max Could you provide more information about how this file is used. As currently you only create a `write-only` file, to be delete on close. Which seems to make no sense in the current case. Is there another process/task reading from that file? Could you please provide a code snippet how you want to read from that file.

Comment: Sure. I am accepting a file as an upload in a rest service. I will eventually pass this file on as a stream to another service, but I need to evaluate the contents of the uploaded file first. Given that the file is quite large, I don't want to store it all in memory. Right now I'm just deleting the file in a `finally` block. This is fine, it just seemed like `DELETE_ON_CLOSE` would have been a better fit, but apparently not.

Comment: @Max Have a look in the new added example. Which works with the `DELETE_ON_CLOSE` option.

Comment: Interesting idea! Thanks.